# Should I ask for my job back after being terminated?

Tags: communication, management, career-development, recruitment, contracts

I have a job as a front end web developer and I really love it because I have a passion for web development. But the problem is, I am always late and have problems regarding tardiness.

My employer and manager decided to terminate my contract since I exceeded the allowed minutes to be late on a month which is a 100 mins. I had been late on my first month for a 152 mins!

My manager told me that it was really a pity because I have skills regarding my job but the real problem is me always being late. I was dumbfounded and said I'm sorry and left the company.

Now I have a new job but I don't feel like myself in that job. It is not bad, but my previous job was still better. I wanted to go back to the previous company I had worked in since it is my very first job where I felt like I'm doing my best. I know I can change so I cannot be late anymore and I wanted to send an email to my manager so I can ask for my job back. I don't know If I'm doing the right thing to ask for my job back or stay in my current job.

I am really confused if I should ask for them to hire me again since I do not have any conflicts with any employees there or became involved in any wrongdoings, I just failed to follow the rules but I'm trying to become a much better employee once I get back.

What should I do?

Comment: what is the new job? is it the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> told me that it was really a pity because I have skills regarding my job

Something like this is usually just said to make you feel better, it's not a high end job requiring special skills. If it was they would have warned you before termination.

I don't advise trying to get your old job back, at least not so soon. If they had thought you worth the effort they would have given you a chance to amend your coming in late at the time.

If your current job finds out you have just started but are already job hunting that may cause you to be terminated as well. One termination so quickly into your career is bad enough, I'd advise against risking another. It's best to learn a lesson from this experience rather than try anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just confused because I'm still young and wandering in life. I should just stay with my current job it is not that bad. Just feeling a little off since I wanted a job where I can hone my skills as a web developer. But no worries I'll just get another job related to that when the right time comes. Again, big thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

It is way too early to ask for a job with the same employer that fired you.

> I am always late and have problems regarding tardiness
>
> My employer and manager decided to terminate my contract since I
>   exceeded the allowed minutes to be late on a month which is a 100
>   mins. I had been late on my first month for a 152 mins!

Many companies have probationary periods where it is easy to justify firing somebody that isn't working out. Every employer knows there are risks with a new employee. They also know that it can take some time to show your abilities, it can take days, weeks, months to become a productive member of the team.

It is important for a new employee to not provide the company with an easy way to fire them during this probationary period. You did just that, you were either very late a handful of times, or consistently late.

> I wanted to go back to the previous company I had worked in since it
>   is my very first job where I felt like I'm doing my best. I know I can
>   change so I cannot be late anymore and I wanted to send an email to my
>   manager so I can ask for my job back. I don't know If I'm doing the
>   right thing to ask for my job back or stay in my current job.

Your manager would have to justify to their management why they should invest any more time and money on somebody they just fired. You would have to explain how they know you have learned your lesson, and have made adjustments to not be late.

Saying you know you can change isn't enough. You have to say I moved to cut my commute in half; or I bought a more reliable car. In other words I was late becasue of X so I have fixed it by doing Y. If the promise is: I will set my alarm 10 minutes earlier, that wouldn't impress me.

> My manager told me that it was really a pity because I have skills
>   regarding my job but the real problem is me always being late.

A month of work isn't much time to demonstrate your range of skills. It is possible that the phrase was an attempt to give you career advice. If you don't start coming to work on time no company will keep you around.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer enlightened me and made question marks in my brain all gone.

Answer (score 1):

As an employer I value the skills and abilities of my employees, however turning up for work late or coming back late from your lunch break too often just doesn't cut the mustard in our organisation.  Tardiness as distinct for having a legitimate excuse for lateness is often seen as laziness or a lack of commitment especially when others are dependant on you.

Learn from your experience and try to step up to the plate in your next job. If getting to work on time isn't your thing consider a job that has flexible hours or self employment where you set the start and finish times but still get the work done and to the required quality standard.

I know of someone who recently got fired (not from my organisation) for spending way too much time on social media rather than doing their work. Be mindful on who is paying your salary and what their performance expectations are.  If getting to work on time is one of them, doing so will be a good start to a healthy employer / employee relationship.  :)

Comment: Thanks! I am now always ahead of time in my new job. Learned my lesson from that experience. Thankfully I did not experience any tardiness on my first week. Hope I can become consistent.